# Directory built from Dockerfile "does not exist"

Tags: docker, file, dockerfile, subdirectory, mkdir

I have a Spring Boot application which clears a folder called "excels" of any excel files before adding any new files. I can find the "excels" file when I run the Spring Boot application but not when running from Docker.

Project structure:

[image]

Code:

```
public void deleteExistingFilesInDirectory() throws IOException {
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("customer-transactions/excels/"));
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir /customer-transactions
RUN groupadd -r tommy && useradd -r -s /bin/false -g tommy tommy
WORKDIR /customer-transactions/home/tommy
COPY src/main /customer-transactions
RUN chown -R tommy:tommy /customer-transactions
USER tommy
CMD tail -f /dev/null

FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18 AS build
RUN mkdir /usr/src/customer-transactions
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/customer-transactions/excels
COPY . /usr/src/customer-transactions
WORKDIR /usr/src/customer-transactions
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:18.0.1.1
RUN mkdir /customer-transactions
COPY --from=build /usr/src/customer-transactions/target/customer-transactions-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /customer-transactions/
EXPOSE 8050
WORKDIR /customer-transactions

CMD java -jar customer-transactions-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When I inspect the running container I can see the "excels" file is created, but I still get the following exception:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: customer-transactions/excels does not exist*

[image]

Comment: The path in the stack trace (`customer-transactions/excels`) looks relative, and the `WORKDIR` is `/customer-transactions`. I'd suspect that the path should be either set absolute (`/customer-transactions/excels`) or relative to the `WORKDIR` (`excels`).

Comment: Setting the path as absolute did the trick.